# Encrypt Spatialite Database using SQL Cipher

Tags: encryption, spatialite, android-database, sqlcipher-android

I'm currently using a spatialite lib given [here](https://github.com/mrenouf/android-spatialite):

What I want is to encrypt the spatialite database, but the problem I don't know where to start.

I'm thinking of using SQLCipher, but If I'am not wrong the sqlcipher replaces all the SQLiteDatabase instances, but how do i do this for spatialite.

Any ideas or has anyone already done something similar? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the link to discussion with geopaparazzi.

https://github.com/geopaparazzi/libjsqlite-spatialite-android/issues/11

I ended up creating two different db one to store my sensitive data and other for spatial related queries.